# How do I use round down function in Camunda literal expression?

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler, dmn, feel-language

I wish to round the result (type long) of literal expression of DMN. I tried using rounddown(exp, -6), but it did not work. Function ceiling and floor also not working. I'm using Camunda 7.17. Please suggest if I'm missing something or any other way to round the result to 6 digits.

Comment: https://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/1.4/Beta1/PDF (Numeric functions in Page 144)

Answer (score 0):

By default recent Camunda versions use the Friendly Enough Expression Language defined in the DMN standard. The FEEL Scala Engine used is documented here: https://camunda.github.io/feel-scala/docs/reference/

You are looking for the built-in numeric functions:
https://camunda.github.io/feel-scala/docs/reference/builtin-functions/feel-built-in-functions-numeric
such as

```
round down(5.5)

round up(5.5) 

floor(1.5)
```